# Easier way to calcuate average change?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, average

I have a product that is getting sent out to the field as it is manufactured and used daily, the use rate changes from day to day based on how the job is going.

I am trying to calculate the average amount of this product used on a daily basis. I need to subtract the amount used from one day to the next, and average them out.

Is there an easier way to do this than `=average((a2-a1),(a3-a2),etc)` ?

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1381471/excel-forecast-future-date-based-on-average-number-of-days-between-a-variable/1381480#1381480

Comment: What type of average (mode, mean, median, etc.)?

Comment: @RonMaupin the word average used loosely as in the above question usually refers to the mean average, and there are also functions specifically for `MODE` and `MEDIAN`, where as `AVERAGE` used in excel also uses `MEAN` average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column A includes the cumulative usage at the end of every day, you don't need to use the `AVERAGE` function at all. You can calculate the average by subtracting the first value from the last value and dividing by the number of days.

Enter this formula in B2 (or any empty cell in row 2)

```
=(A2-A$1)/ROWS(A$2:A2)
```

And copy it down to the other cells in the same column. B2 will now show the average daily usage after one day, C2 will show the average daily usage over the first two days, and so on.

[image: Example of usage]

Comment: Of course! Now I feel stupid! I knew there was a better way!

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a column "Delta" subtracting a1-a2 on b2, a2-a3 on b3 and so on - easy to drag & drop down ... and calculate the average of that column

Comment: I thought about that, but that data isn't something that we are using, and I'm currently in the process of trying to make this spreadsheet less bulky.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array function. For example, all the values are in column A1 to A10, the function:

```
={average(A1:A9-A2:A10)}
```

just type "`=average(A1:A9-A2:A10)`"

The curly brackets show it's an array function, and you get this by holding Ctrl+Shift as you hit Enter to leave the cell.

This will give you the average difference in one cell. You could also use Sum, StdDev.S, etc.

Answer (score -1):

**Considering popular business practices, I would like to suggest Weighted Average method to find the forthcoming price of products in Table.**

*To achieve the goal you need few other information to add to the Sales Table are, **Quantity Sold** and **Total Sale**.*

*Below is the Sample Table along with calculated values, finds the **Average Price** of each product.*

*The mechanism behind the calculation is:*

```
(First Day Price*First Day Qty)+(Second Day Price*Second Day Qty)+,,,/Total Qty
```

[image]

**How it works:**

- Data Range for the Sales Table is `A1:E13` including Headers.
- Formula for **Quantity Sold** in Cell `B16` is:

  ```
  =SUMIFS($D$2:$D$13,$A$2:$A$135,  $A16)
  ```
- Cell `C16` has Formula for **Total Sale.**

  ```
  =SUMIFS($E$2:$E$13,$A$2:$A$13,$A16)
  ```
- Average Price Formula in Cell `D16`.

  ```
  =CEILING(C16/D16,2)
  ```

**N.B.**

- **Fill all the Formula Down.**
- I've used the `CEILING` Function to *Round up the Price*, you may use `ROUND` or `ROUNDUP` also.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.

Comment: Write your concern,, why down voted this post??